# Setting the value of a domain class defined in differen domain

Tags: java

I have two domain classes (getter setter of two tables): `Contact Information` and `Address`.
I have some fields in Contact Information and some fields in Address.

I'm setting the values of the contact information in the controller class but I need to set the values of fields in Address class via Contact Information.

Code:

```
class ContactInformation {

String id;
String name;

Address address;

//getter and setters

}
```

And

```
Class Address{

String idAddress;
...
...
//getter and setter

}
```

In Controller class

I am setting the values like

```
contactInformation.setId("some value");
```

How do i set the value of idAddress via ContactInformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
contactInformation.getAddress().setIdAddress(id)
```